# Custom css to Sveltestrap Button

Tags: bootstrap-4, svelte

I want to change the focus property on the sveltestrap Button component.  How should I target the component? There is no prop to add custom css.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library seems to spread `{...$$restProps}` [here](https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap/blob/c74aab90cd8bc5965d5fa9364018de5e2091163b/src/Button.svelte#L35). So you could add a custom class that can alter the focus.

This should probably help you achieve it check [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ed4eae8952b54008b16a5515d622356f?version=3.38.1)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without using the global property?